# jquery change background colour of empty required inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form that has both required and non required fields and I want to change the background colour of only the required inputs that are empty when the user submits the form.

The required fields have a class called 'required'

```
$('#audit_submit').click(function(){
   if($('.required').val() == '') 
    {
           $('.required').css('background-color' , '#FF0000');
        }
});
```

All this does is if all of the fields are empty it changes all of them but if one isn't it doesn't change any of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **[.each()](http://api.jquery.com/each/)** here to loop through all `.required` elements:

```
$('#audit_submit').click(function(){
    $('.required').each(function() {
        if($(this).val() == '') {
           $(this).css('background-color' , '#FF0000');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: @Felix ,Please explain your answer.

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/8MEb8/)</kbd>

[.filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) all the elements whose value is `''` and than appy `.css('background-color', '#FF0000');` to filtered elements.

To reset colors use `.css('background-color', '#fff')`

```
$('#audit_submit').click(function () {
    $('.required').css('background-color', '#fff').filter(function () {
        return $.trim(this.value) === '';
    }).css('background-color', '#FF0000');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Working fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/sV8QG/

```
$('p').click(function(){
   if($('.required').val() == '') 
    {
           $('.required').css('background-color' , '#FF0000');
        }
    else{
           $('.required').css('background-color' , 'white');
    }
});
```